# Restore KeServiceDescriptorTable

Tags: windows, kernel

There's a rootkit which I want to get rid off. But it hooked KeServiceDescriptorTable so I can't use functions to remove it from registries/etc. I need to get address of original nt* bypassing KeServiceDescriptorTable. I was thinking to take those addresses from ntoskrnl.exe file by counting offsets etc. Is it a good idea, is there sth else I could do?

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Quickest solution to this problem is to reinstall the OS.

Comment: The best approach is probably to boot from removable media, e.g., a Windows Vista or later installation DVD, and delete the files and registry settings from there.  To manipulate the registry of an offline system, load the hives from the \windows\system32\config directory on the target disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use GMER to remove the malicious service, and reboot.